# Batch replace with linefeed character

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file I have a variable with text that may include spaces delimited by semicolons.
The variable may be empty, and the text has trailing semicolons.

```
set Something=1 2;3 4;5 6;
set Nothing=
```

How can I print each of them delimited by the semicolon?

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Trying to use replace, but don't know how to specify a linefeed:

```
echo %Something:;=<<WhatToUseForLinefeed>>%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%e IN ("%something:;=" "%") DO IF "%%~e" neq "" ECHO %%~e
```

Replace all `;` in `something` with `" "`, so the string seen by the `for` is `"1 2" "3 4" "5 6" ""`. This is four quoted strings separated by spaces. We don't want the last, where `%%e` would be assigned `""`, so if `"%%~e"` is `""` don't `echo` it. `%%e` will be quoted, `%%~e` dequotes `%%e`.

Tip: Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you have asked for:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Something=1 2;3 4;5 6;"
echo !Something:;=^
%Don't remove this line%
!
```

The character ^ is interpreted as ignoring a special meaning for the character that follows it (if there is one), therefore specifying a ^ before a line break followed by an empty line is the way to define an ASCII 10 character (LineFeed).

The trick to replace characters by LineFeeds is to use `!delayed!` expansion, not `%standard%` expansion...